# glob2 install using IDLE on Mac

Tags: python, python-idle, macos-high-sierra

So, my exercise says to use glob2 but I tried like six ways and never could get the module installed. I am using IDLE for my terminal. When I open the folder that has all the modules in it, I see pip and glob.
I am using python 3.8, IDLE on a Mac using High Sierra

I tried:
import pip     #got no error
pip install glob2
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Also tried this:

> > > pip.install('glob2')
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >           pip.install('glob2')
> > >       NameError: name 'pip' is not defined

I then looked up the path and tried using that:

> > > import sys; sys.executable
> > >       '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8'
> > >       /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -m pip install glob2
> > >       SyntaxError: invalid syntax

at this point I am at a loss. The last suggestion was posted here: https://www.honchosearch.com/blog/seo/install-python-modulespackage-using-idle-mac/

Comment: IDLE is *not* a terminal, it's just an interactive interpreter. You need to open Mac's terminal and run `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -m pip install glob2` there.

Comment: Ahh.. I see. I misunderstood and thought that IDLE held it's own library for python.. which is strange because when I run python in os term, it says it is v 2.7, but in IDLE it is 3.8

Comment: 'python' is linked to the Python 2.7 included with macOS.  It includes a buggy decade-old or ore version of tcl/tk, so the included IDLE for 2.7 does not run well.  I would not touch it.  'python3.8' is linked to the Python 3.8 installed, for instance, by the 3.8 installed at python.org.  In terminal, 'python3.8' should be sufficient (it works for me), without the full path.